# In Word 2010, is it possible to remove the word "Comment" from Balloon Comments?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I would like to remove the word "Comment" from my Word 2010 documents as there are many comments on each page.  It just seems like it's wasted space.  Excel will allow the user to backspace over the word "Comment" but Word will not.

Comment: You can change the username but cannot delete the "Comment" word. Should I tell you the method to change the username if this can help you?

Comment: I know how to change the name, thanks.  Do you know if there is a way to tell Word not to scale the printed document.  When adding balloon comments, the original document is scaled to fit the remaining amount of space by reducing the font size to retain the text wrap.  I would prefer that Word re-wrap the text with the original, bigger font so that it's readable..... Any thoughts?

Comment: You should consider re-wording your question to incorporate what's in your last comment or ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Not if you are printing the document and the markup. You can print the document without showing the comments and it will not rescale the document. You can print just the markup list separately as a separate document to go along with it.